# Add a number to get prime number in python

Tags: python, optimization, primes

The program is to get the nearest prime number to a number. I solved the problem but I wish to optimize the code.

```
import time
def isprime(a ,d):
    b=a
    c=0
    f=b**(0.5)
    for i in range(1,int(f)+1):
        if a%i==0 and c<=1:
            c+=1
    if c==1:
        return d.append(b)
    else:
        b=a+1
        isprime(b,d)

start=time.time()        
b=[89, 54,36, 74, 44, 19, 12]   # Input
d=[]
for i in b:
    isprime(i,d)     #function call
print(d)             #output is [89, 59, 37, 79, 47, 19, 13]
stop=time.time()
print(stop-start)    #0.0001347064971923828 Seconds
```

Help with Code optimization. I'm just a beginner I know code is of lower. Help to learn bit of coding.

Comment: You might have better luck at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've flagged for migration to CR per [_this meta post_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353)

Comment: How to migrate this question to Code Review. I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: @Deepan see [the post that I included a link to in my previous comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353). I have flagged this post for moderator intervention, requesting it be migrated.

Comment: @Deepan since you appear to have [cross-posted on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/244179/120114) I have retracted my flag; I still voted to close this post because it doesn't seem to be on-topic on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code can be rewritten for easier readability and improved performance as follows.

**Code Refactoring**

```
def is_prime(n):
  " Returns True if prime False otherwise "

  # Base cases
  if n < 2:
    return False
  if n == 2:
    return True
  if n % 2 == 0:
    return False

  # checking odd numbers 3, 5, ...
  return next((False for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2) if n % i == 0), True)

def next_prime(n):
  " First prime number greater or equal to n "
  if n <= 2:
    return 2

  while not is_prime(n):
    if n % 2:
      n += 2  # stay on odd
    else:
      n += 1  # switch to odd

  return n

def next_prime_batch(b):
  " Finds next prime for a batch of numbers "
  return [next_prime(x) for x in b]
```

**Performance Improvement**

Result:

- 63% faster for original small numbers (Test 1 below)
- 10X faster for larger numbers (Test 2 below)

**Test**

Tested using timeit for higher accuracy

*Original code made into function*

```
def isprime(a, d):
    b=a
    c=0
    f=b**(0.5)

    for i in range(1,int(f)+1):
        if a%i==0 and c<=1:
            c+=1

    if c==1:
        return d.append(b)
    else:
        b=a+1
        isprime(b,d)

def calc_next_primes(b):
  d=[]
  for i in b:
      isprime(i,d)     #function call
  return b
```

*Timing Code*

Test 1--Only slight improvement for smaller numbers

```
b = [2, 89, 54,36, 74, 44, 19, 12]
count = 10000  # number of timing iterations
print(timeit(lambda: calc_next_primes(b), number = count))
print(timeit(lambda: next_prime_batch(b), number = count))
# calc_next_primes: 1.4129 seconds for 10K iterations
# next_prime_batch: 0.8683 seconds for 10K iterations
```

Test 2--10x improvement for larger numbers

```
b = [12346, 1920131, 219112, 1423231]
count = 1000  # number of timing iterations
print(timeit(lambda: calc_next_primes(b), number = count))
print(timeit(lambda: next_prime_batch(b), number = count))
# calc_next_primes: 7.8703 seconds for 1K iterations
# next_prime_batch: 0.6200 seconds for 1K iterations
```

Answer (score 0):

The quality of this code is as much an issue, from my perspective, as the performance.  (Variable names `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `f`, really?)  The code needs a little better understanding of primes and a little more attention to code readability (and to a lesser extent, separating testing from the code itself):

```
def is_odd_prime(number):

    for divisor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

def prime_ceiling(number):

    if number <= 2:
        return 2

    number |= 1  # enforce odd

    while not is_odd_prime(number):
        number += 2

    return number

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from time import time

    numbers = [89, 54, 36, 74, 44, 19, 12]

    start = time()

    primes = [prime_ceiling(number) for number in numbers]

    stop = time()

    print(primes)
    print(stop - start)
```

Avoid measuring the I/O time of printing your results, just measure how long it takes to calculate them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question will be.

```
from math import sqrt
from time import time
def prime_no(n):
    if n==1:
        return False 
    if n<=3:
        return True 
    if n%2==0 or n%3==0:
        return False 
    for i in range(5,int(sqrt(n))+1,6):
        if n%i==0 or n%(i+2)==0:
            return False 
    return True
a=time()
l=[89, 54,36, 74, 44, 19, 12]   #input
maxi=max(l)
while (prime_no(maxi)==False):
    maxi+=1 
k=[True for i in range(maxi+1)]
p=2 
while(p*p<=maxi):
    if(k[p]==True):
        for i in range(p*p,maxi+1,p):
            k[i]=False 
    p+=1 
for i in l:
    f=i
    while k[f]==False:
        f+=1 
    print(f,end=' ')
z=time()
print("Time: {:.20f}".format(z-a))    #89 59 37 79 47 19 13 Time: 0.00011634826660156250
```

This program is much optimized as for the input of 99999 numbers the time is 0.38797283172607421875 Seconds

Comment: The code produces the wrong result for 0 (-> 0) and 1 (-> 1) should they be in the input.